# aws s3 cp returns An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

#### Foreword

I guess it may be a duplication but other posts with the same problem didn't help me much.

#### A problem

`aws s3 cp s3://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-test-bucket/intro.jpg test.jpg`
Outputs the following:
`fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1539624480514",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1539624478431",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Some notes

1. `intro.jpg` was added by user A (who has AdministratorAccess) via AWS Console Dashboard (it's not copy file between buckets)
2. `aws sts get-caller-identity` returns me information about user A

   ```js
   {
       "UserId": "AIDXXXX3KDQHYYYYXRLO",
       "Account": "765123991235",
       "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::765123991235:user/john.doe@example.com"
   }
   ```
3. `cat ~/.aws/config`

```js
[default]
region = us-west-2
output = json
```

4. `cat ~/.aws/credentials` points to user A access key and secret

```js
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AZZZIXXXXJQZA6YYYYUQ
aws_secret_access_key = <<<<<<<<<KEY REMOVED>>>>>>>>
```

5. `aws s3 ls` returns the correct list of buckets
6. time is synced on my local machine correctly

Comment: Does user A represent an IAM user in the same account as my-test-bucket? Also, as a general rule, that S3 bucket policy is not the best security practice.

Comment: Yes, it does. I use this policy for testing only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`s3://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-test-bucket/intro.jpg` refers to a bucket named `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` and the object key `my-test-bucket/intro.jpg`.

Access is denied because that isn't your bucket.

The correct URI here would be `s3://my-test-bucket/intro.jpg`.